# Why can't I change a mapView in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

In my app I have added a MapView. At this moment I want to change some of the properties in xCode (IB). I am presented with a lock and no changes happened. What could be the case?

Second, while I'm asking anyway, I want to change the view to be maximized. I really want to zoom in on the users location. Ricght now (cause I'm in the Netherlands) I see the half of Europe.
Tips and tricks are very welcome.

Regards,

Adri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoom user location:

```
- (IBAction)showCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
self.mapview.showsUserLocation=YES;
self.mapview.delegate = self;
[self.mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Localization Locking** option in the **File Inspector**, you probably have selected an option there, that prevents you from changing (some) properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a region that show one kilometer on each side of the user's current location

```
 MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(MapView.userLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000); 
 MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [self.mapview regionThatFits:region];
 [self.mapview setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: I need a bit more help if possible.

Comment: I created a property for my mapview and synthesized it. After that I created a (void) method with your code in it. My map however is still very small. Here's the code: -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView didUpdateUserLocation: (MKUserLocation *)userlocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 100, 100);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
} Please advice